# PLSQL SELECT INTO FROM parameter

Tags: sql, plsql

I created a function that should return the max id from a table(parameter)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getmaxid
(
P_TABLE IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN NUMBER IS
v_maxId NUMBER(38);

BEGIN

SELECT MAX(id) INTO v_maxId FROM P_TABLE;

RETURN v_maxId;

END getmaxid
```

However, i keep getting the error message "**ORA-00942: table or view does not exist**" on this line:

```
SELECT MAX(id) INTO v_maxId FROM P_TABLE;
```

Comment: P_Table is a variable, not a table name.  If you need to use dynamic SQL, read up on the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like explained earlier, you need to use dynamic SQL to perform the operation. In this case, p_table is a variable. The solution to this is to build a string that will contain the SQL and dynamically execute it one you've build the query.

The example below uses, DUAL, but the table name is arbitrary.

Here is what you're looking for, take the function outside of the block, I left it like this so that you can test it..

```
DECLARE
   FUNCTION getmaxid (p_table IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
      v_maxid    NUMBER (38);
      v_select   VARCHAR2 (200);
      cnt        SYS_REFCURSOR;
   BEGIN
      v_select := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || p_table;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_select);

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_select INTO v_maxid;

      RETURN v_maxid;
   END getmaxid;
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (getmaxid ('DUAL'));
END;
```